# adb input swipe to unlock slide screen lock and open notifications

Tags: adb, samsung-galaxy-nexus

When I use the command `adb input swipe`, the slider slides all the way to the right, but does not 'click', so the screen does not unlock. I calculate the coordinates based on the (not visible) 'swipe area'. The same issue occurs when I try to drag the notifications open, I slide it all the way down, but it does not 'click' so notifications don't stay open.

I am using python 2.7 to call the adb functions, I think that may play a role too, but I've tried every form of `os.system`, `subprocess.Popen`, and `subprocess.call` I can think of.

Any idea how I can make this work?